# Binding AngularJS value to call existing JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some existing JavaScript I need to call. My existing function is called 'confirmDelete'. For the sake of demonstration, the shortened version looks like this:

```
function confirmDelete(orderId) {
  return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Order #"' + orderId + '"?');
}
```

There is more to this function. Either way, I am trying to call this function like this:

```
<a href="~/order/delete/{{order.Id}}" onclick="return confirmDelete('{{order.Id}}');">delete order</a>
```

My other bindings are working. However, I cannot figure out how to pass the order ID to my existing JavaScript function. How do I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you define the confirm function a in scope and replace onclick with ng-click ?

Answer (score 1):

You could inject `$window`:

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {
    $scope.window = $window;
});
```

and then you can do:

```
<a href="~/order/delete/{{order.Id}}" ng-click="window.confirmDelete(order.Id);">delete order</a>
```

Or you can add

```
$scope.confirmDelete = function(id) {
    return window.confirmDelete(id);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
<a href="~/order/delete/{{order.Id}}" ng-click="confirmDelete(order.Id);">delete order</a>
```

Or you could create a pass-through method for any global function:

```
$scope.callGlobal(fn, params) {
    if (!angular.isArray(params)) {
        params = [params];
    }
    return window[fn].apply(window, params)
}
```

Which takes the function name, and an array of params (or, if just one argument, you can pass just the argument), and then you can do

```
<a href="~/order/delete/{{order.Id}}" ng-click="callGlobal('confirmOrder', order.Id);">delete order</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<a href="~/order/delete/{{order.Id}}" onclick="return confirmDelete('{{order.Id}}');">delete order</a>
```

try

```
<a href="~/order/delete/{{order.Id}}" ng-click="return confirmDelete(order.Id);">delete order</a>
```

I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxf20erg/4/) , although you should use globals like i did

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xxf20erg/6/), as per Mike said

Comment: I don't think that will work, since it's not suppressing the default click behavior when the user click "cancel". The fiddle is working because the href="..." was changed from href="~/order/..." to href="#/{{item.id}}". If you change the href back to a server route, it will follow it regardless. This would have the effect of deleting the order no matter how the user responds to the "Are you sure..." confirmation.

Comment: oh, i see, thatswhy you added the preventDeault ! @Mike

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng-click directive instead of the non-Angular onclick handler, and pass the $event object as well.

In the controller:

```
 $scope.confirmDelete = function(orderId, $event) {
   if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to delete Order #"' + orderId + '"?')) {
      $event.preventDefault();
   }
 }
```

Then you can reference it in your html with

```
     <a href="~/order/delete/{{order.Id}}" ng-click="confirmDelete(order.Id, $event)">delete order</a>
```

here's a working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/p8Bm0WI7skVZFH3rhTun?p=preview

Also, you could actually just leave the href="..." out and handle the view change in the controller function as well.

Comment: and if you left the href="..." out and handle the change in the controller, then you wouldn't have to deal with the $event object at all, since you wouldn't have to deal with preventing the default click behavior.

Comment: another clarification: the extra $event object code is only required if your href="..." is a server route, vs. an Angular one (i.e. href="#something" vs. the href="~/something" like you showed). If you're doing a server route, as you showed in your question, you have to prevent the click from following the href in the case where "cancel" is selected.